# how to read delimiter "|" vertical line in R external csv file

Tags: r, csv

In R, how does one read delimiter or and also convert delimiter for "|" vertical line (ASCII: | |). I need to split on whole numbers inside the file, so strsplit() does not help me.

I have R code that reads csv file, but it still retains the vertical line "|" character. This file has a separator of "|" between fields. When I try to read with read.table() I get comma, "," separating every individual character. I also try to use dplyr in R for tab_spanner_delim(delim = "|") to convert the vertical line after the read.delim("file.csv", sep="|") read the file, even this read.delmin() does not work. I new to special char R programming.

```
read.table(text = gsub("|", ",", readLines("file.csv")))

dat_csv <- read.delim("file.csv", sep="|")

x <- cat_csv %>% tab_spanner_delim(delim = "|")
```

dput() from read.table(text = gsub("|", ",", readLines("file.csv")))

```
",\",R,D,|,I,|,7,8,|,0,1,0,|,0,0,1,2,|,8,8,1,0,1,|,1,|,7,|,1,0,5,|,1,1,6,|,1,9,9,9,1,2,2,0,|,0,0,:,0,0,|,|,A,M,|,6,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,\",", 
",\",R,D,|,I,|,7,8,|,0,1,0,|,0,0,1,2,|,8,8,1,0,1,|,1,|,7,|,1,0,5,|,1,1,6,|,1,9,9,9,1,2,2,6,|,0,0,:,0,0,|,4,.,9,|,|,6,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,\","
```

dput() from dat_csv <- read.delim("file.csv", sep="|")

```
"RD|I|78|010|0012|88101|1|7|105|116|19991220|00:00||AM|6|||||||||||||", 
"RD|I|78|010|0012|88101|1|7|105|116|19991226|00:00|4.9||6|||||||||||||"
```

dput(dat_csv)

```
"RD|I|78|010|0012|88101|1|7|105|116|19991220|00:00||AM|6|||||||||||||", 
"RD|I|78|010|0012|88101|1|7|105|116|19991226|00:00|4.9||6|||||||||||||"
```

Comment: Can you post first few lines of `file.csv` ?

Comment: I did. the dput() at the last is that example

Comment: And you want each value separated by `'|'` in a new column?

Comment: Yes, each numeric need to be a new column as separated by "|"

Comment: Can you check if this works for you? `data <- read.table(text = paste0(trimws(readLines('file.csv'), whitespace = '[", ]'), collapse = '\n'), sep = '|')`

Comment: ok let me check, thanks

Comment: wow, the best solution, thanks. some one else helped but all char were replaced with comma, like 459.5 turned into 4,5,7,.,5

Comment: Do you mean the file is still being read incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read the data line by line using `readLines`. Remove unwanted characters at the end of each line using `trimws`, paste the string into one string with new line (`\n`) character as the `collapse` argument and use this string in `read.table` to read data as dataframe.

```
data <- read.table(text = paste0(trimws(readLines('file.csv'), 
                   whitespace = '[", ]'), collapse = '\n'), sep = '|')
```